# What is the "make install" replacement command in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

There is a command in ubuntu that you can use instead of the "make install" when installing software compiled from source.

It adds some things to the system to allow the software to be removed later.

Can anyone remember what that command is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps **checkinstall** ? This is the one I use, it creates an rpm package that you can install and easily remove later.

Comment: in the case of ubuntu, it makes debs, but yes, checkinstall is what he should use.